# Where to find a free style for my WPF applicaton?

Tags: wpf

I am not happy with the default style of my application and I'd like to add a style that makes it look more professional. I downloaded some themes but the ones I found kinda ruined my window interfaces.

Any idea where to find free recent WPF styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not exist anything like this, what you are describing. You can get Windows themes, which will impact your whole OS but also your application if you have been using system colors while developing.

There is no magic formula that would know how to style  which button. This is something you have to implement on your own.

What you can do is to learn more about how to properly style an application using styles from from a external  . In order to make your application more appealing you can download a color pallet and follow it. The designing you will, still, have to do on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are themes pre-made available on the internet. : http://brianlagunas.com/free-metro-light-and-dark-themes-for-wpf-and-silverlight-microsoft-controls/

You need to add them to you project.